# Check at run time if primary key exists

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am working in asp.net. I have a textbox named `formidtxt` and another textbox is `colortxt`. Now what I want is that when a user enters an Form ID in `formidtxt` then at the same time it should start checking whether there already exists a form id with same ID that has been entered and if Form ID already exists in database then the color of `colortxt` textbox should change to red else it should be green.

I have an idea that it can be done by using events in text boxes but can't understand the working. My database is in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: ask you asking for help on `text box` events or `SQL Server` query ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this C# code;

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // formidtxt is the name of the textbox
    this.formidtxt.TextChanged += FormIDTextBox_TextChanged;
    formidtxt.AutoPostBack = true;
}
```

Note that this method was written inside the Page_Load method.

`TextChanged` is an event and it occurs when the text is modified in a TextBox.
In this case,  when the `formidtxt` (textbox) text changes, it will call the `FormIDTextBox_TextChanged` method.

```
private void FormIDTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0;

    // convert textbox text (string) to int
    Int32.TryParse(formidtxt.Text, out x);

    // call IsIDAvailableDAO method
    // x is the converted int value
    if (IsIDAvailableDAO(x))
    {
        colortxt.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        colortxt.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
}
```

This method will get the text from the textbox (`formidtxt`) and send it to the `IsIDAvailableDAO` method as a parameter.

Using the `IsIDAvailableDAO` method, we can check whether the ID is available in the database or not. If it is available, then the method will return a `TRUE` boolean value. If not, it will return a `False` boolean value.

According to that boolean value, you can change the color of the `colortxt` textbox as you want or do something else.

```
private Boolean IsIDAvailableDAO(int id)
{
    Boolean output;

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Testing;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string query = @"SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(ID) >= 1 THEN CAST( 1 as BIT ) ELSE CAST( 0 as BIT )  
                        END As IsAvailable
                        FROM TableName
                        WHERE ID = @ID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        myConnection.Open();

        output = (Boolean)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        myConnection.Close();
    }

    return output;
}
```

In this method (`IsIDAvailableDAO`), Please change the query (`TableName`, `ID`, etc.) and `connectionstring` as appropriate.

You also has to add this namespace: `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces